# How can I use dynamic colors in SplashScreen api an android 12?

Tags: android, android-12, android-splashscreen, android-api-31

I'm trying to make the background of an android 12 splash screen use @android:color/system_neutral1_900 as the background, but as I can see, the color loads only after the splash screen. Is there any way to use it on the splash screen?

```xml
<style name="Theme.App.SplashScreen" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <!-- Set the splash screen background, animated icon, and animation duration. -->
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@android:color/system_neutral1_900</item>
</style>
```

The color does not appear and it uses the default grey. I also tried with other system_ colors and the same result comes up. Using @android:color/black or hex colors works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this item as part of your main application theme according to this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#set-theme)

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi. My problem wasn't that I cannot theme the splash screen, it was that I can not use the system dynamic colors (monet colors) for theming it. If I set windowSplashScreenBackground to a color like @android:color/black it works. I just want to use dynamic colors, as my app uses it and I don't like the transition from that simple white to the one with a tint. Thank you though for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the splash screen background color item.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35418659)